# wordpress edited stylesheet is reset and attached image is gone after a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I followed this [post](http://blog.webjames.co.uk/hosting-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-with-the-svbtle-theme-for-free/201/) to setup a wordpress site hosted on Heroku.

As an admin, I edited the stylesheet(style.css) and uploaded some images. It all works and the site is updated successfully. But after a while when I check the site again, our customized codes in the stylesheet and the images uploaded are gone.

Anyone can help me figure out why it happened and how should I fix it?

Comment: The only explication is that the files are being removed and the style sheet is being replaced by an old one. There could be a few reasons why this could be happening, but my first guess would be something with the host or some server backup process. Check the modified dates on the files to see if they are being reverted to old ones.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell Yes I think so. How could I prevent that?

Comment: It would most likely be something related to your host, so I would contact them.

Comment: WordPress is written in PHP – it is not a Ruby on Rails application. How are you editing the code? Locally, then pushing to Heroku with Git?

Comment: @ctshryock Sorry it was a mistake. It's not a Rails app. Just corrected it.I editted with wordpress admin dashboard, so it was not locally.

Comment: no worries :)  are those changes recorded in the database or on file? The Heroku dyno is ephemeral; any change to disk will be lost on after idle or cycling. You need to change it in code and push with git, or make sure the changes are in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the same question and answer here:

"The problem is because Heroku doesn't allow you to have persistent storage on the Dynos. So initially when you upload the image it'll work but Heroku will sometimes restart your Dyno or move it to some other host (as they constantly shift applications to load balance their servers).

In order to make sure that your images stay online you should use a Wordpress Plugin that uploads to a persistent storage service such as Amazon S3. You could give this plugin a try: Amazon S3 for WordPress

The great thing about using Amazon S3 is that it's free for the first year if you use their Free Tier. You will have some limits but if it's a low traffic site, you shouldn't go beyond them easily."

[Wordpress Heroku Featured Images not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182666/wordpress-heroku-featured-images-not-showing)